# Is there any scenario for Executor instead of ExecutorService. Intention behind Executor interface?

Tags: java, executorservice, executor

I am wondering if there is any reason to use an Executor instead of an ExecutorService.

As far as I know there is no implementation of the `Executor` interface in the JDK which is not also an `ExecutorService` which means you have to shut the service down so that there are no memory leaks. You cannot shut an `Executor` down but you can do that with an `ExecutorService`.

So, is there any scenario in which you would use something like that:

```
private final Executor _executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

What is the intention behind the `Executor`interface? Examples appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*JavaDoc* is your friend in this case

> This interface provides a way of decoupling task submission from the
>   mechanics of how each task will be run, including details of thread
>   use, scheduling, etc

Further down you read

> However, the Executor interface does not strictly require that
>   execution be asynchronous. In the simplest case, an executor can run
>   the submitted task immediately in the caller's thread:

```
 class DirectExecutor implements Executor {
     public void execute(Runnable r) {
         r.run();
     }
 }
```

These definitions are already expressive to me.

Regarding your usage example. Imho, no, I would never use this interface like that.
**However** it might be used as an *accepted* argument.

E.g. I want to run a task, but I'd like the user of my method to decide how this task is run.

```
public void run(final Executor taskExecutor) {
   taskExecutor.execute(this.myTaskRunnable);
}
```

The `Executor` implementation could be any behind the scene, it might be synchronous (like the example above) or asynchronous but I don't really care.
It's the *user* which will take care of handling it.